# Safest way to get the Invoke MethodInfo from Action<T>'s Instance

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, delegates, action

I am currently working on an extension method that facilitates what the question's title suggests.

I could, of course. use the GetMetohd("Invoke") method call on the type and be done with it,
But something tells me this is not the "safest" way to go.
Classes and types may change, including those in the BCL.

So I've come up with the following LINQ statement, which works just fine:

```
 public static class ActionExtensions
{
    public static MethodInfo GetInvoke<T>(this Action<T> obj)
    {
        var actionType = obj.GetType();
        var tType= typeof(T);

        return (
             from methodInfo
             in actionType.GetMethods()
             let par = methodInfo.GetParameters()
             where par.Length == 1 && par[0].ParameterType == tType
             select methodInfo
             ).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

The thing is, even this feels somewhat iffy, since one day Action can change and contain another method with such traits.. even if I add the "HasGenericParameters" constraint, there's no assurance of safety.

Do you have any ideas regarding a way to obtain the exact MethodInfo instance relevant to

```
"Action<T>.Invoke()"
```

Comment: `Action<T>` has a .Method property already that returns the MethodInfo for that exact method behind the delegate.

Comment: Searching for how to invoke a delegate using reflection emit (and I assume you want this) everyone seems to depend on `GetMethod("Invoke")`. The .NET developers can never do anything to break all this code. I think it is safe to rely on this.

Comment: @EyalPerry glad it's helpful. Feel free to mark the answer 'accepted' if it sufficiently resolved your question.

Comment: @EyalPerry what is actually your intention?

Comment: @usr I am implementing an Event Aggregator, much Like MvvmLight's Messenger, which notifies subscribers based on the message object's actual type. if you used Galasoft's Messenger you would know this to be a great issue. this whole MethodInfo thing was a little bump in that road :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding your intent, this whole approach seems unnecessary. You can acquire the MethodInfo for the exact method behind a delegate like so:

```
Action<Foo> myAction = //get delegate...
MethodInfo theMethod = myAction.Method;
```

If the `Action<T>` is wrapped around a specific instance's method, that instance is available from the `myAction.Target` property.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding, but that your answer is useful nonetheless. I think the question is specifically about the `Action<T>.Invoke` method. But `Action<Foo> myAction = _ => { }; myAction = new Action<Foo>(myAction.Invoke); MethodInfo theMethod = myAction.Method;` should work, and is essentially what you have in your answer already.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! and nonetheless, I think you understood clearly what I was asking, it is just my lack of experience with Action.

Comment: Rex M, FYI, Action<T>.Method returns a MethodInfo to the underlying object's method, as in, the actual instance whose Method I passed as Action<T>, if one, would like to invoke it using reflection, he would also need to keep around the object reference itself, whereas in my implementation with LINQ, I only needed to keep their Action<T> reference around because they encapsulated both instance and method delegate. for future googlers. I will sum up, 
methodInfo.Invoke(obj,param) with Rex M's impl obj would be the object whose method it is. in my case, obj would be the Action<T> reference itself

Comment: @EyalPerry the specific instance tied to the `Action<T>` is available from the `.Target` property, so you don't need to hold onto the instance separately... as long as you have the Action, you can grab the MethodInfo and the instance from it: `myAction.MethodInfo.Invoke(myAction.Target, {args});`